# What is the proper method to reuse handlers/callbacks in Socket.io events, and does it even matter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to factor out the anonymous callback functions from my `socket.on()` events for two reasons:

1. It makes the code slightly easier to read and document.
2. I believe it can be more memory efficient.

Since the first reason is more of a personal preference, I will not address it--although I am definitely interested in seeing style guides and/or general recommendations.

The second reason is because the only way I have seen socket.io used is like this:

```
var io = require('socketio');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('event', function(data) {
        // logic goes here
        socket.emit('different event', differentData);
    });
});
```

This can work quite well, but I believe the anonymous functions are instantiated for each and every incoming connection.

I would factor this out through the following:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('event', eventHandler);

    function eventHandler(data) {
        // logic goes here
        socket.emit('different event', differentData);
    });
});
```

Still, that appears to still create an instance of 'eventHandler' for every new connection.

My current attempt at factoring this out looks like this:

```
var sockets = {}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', login.bind(socket));
    socket.on('get information', getInformation);
});

function login(data) {
    // logic goes here

    // Save the socket to a persistent object
    sockets[data.userId] = this;

    this.emit('logged in', loginData);
});

function getInformation(data) {
    // authentication, db access logic goes here

    // Avoid binding by using previously stored socket
    sockets[data.userId].emit('got information', infoData);
});
```

This works, but I am believe that bind() just creates another function, anyway, subverting any real benefit of not including the `login` callback in the `connection` callback.

As for the other handlers, it seems that a persistent object is necessary, as evidenced by [EtherPad's method (SocketIORouter.js:62)](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/develop/src/node/handler/SocketIORouter.js#L62). Since I plan to be listening to a sizable number of events, it seems like pulling the callbacks out of the `connection` callback is the best way to go about it. Maybe bind will create a new function each time it is called, but in this case, it will only be called *twice* per connection rather than 10-20 times. I imagine that for thousands of clients, that would make a difference, but I am not sure.

So, to sum up, is this a proper approach, or is there perhaps a better one that I should be using? Or, is this just another case of premature optimization?

Comment: It's premature optimization.  Functions are created (and then GCed) every time, but for tiny functions it doesn't matter, they're cheap and V8 is good at optimizing them.  Also I recommend using named function expressions eg: `io.on('connection', function onConnection(socket) { . . . });` they show their names in the stack traces.

Comment: One thing to think about is whether the creation of a new Function instance is actually an expensive thing. Keep in mind that creating a new Function object does not necessarily mean that the code is replicated - the runtime can take advantage of the fact that the code is invariant and share it between instances.

Comment: bind() also creates a new function, every time. if you used only pure functions, then they would be completely re-usable. it's still much nicer to report and maintain named functions however, so for that reason alone you should keep your code improvements. also, as long as a function is identical to another already-parsed function, the internal function can be re-used without duplication; that goes even for anons defined in a call, as long as they don't use closure.

Comment: Interesting food for thought. Thanks!